# How to understand the pivot matrix of scipy.linalg.lu_factor?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I manually reconstruct a matrix *A* that was factorized by [lu_factor](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu_factor.html)? (*A* = *PLU*)

My current attempts all failed due to the setup of matrix *P*. Here is what I have so far:

```
A = np.random.rand(3,3)
lu, piv = lu_factor(A)

U = np.triu(lu)
L = np.tril(lu, -1)
L[np.diag_indices_from(L)] = 1.0
```

I am looking for the matrix *P* that makes this line print *True*:

```
print np.allclose(A, np.dot(P, np.dot(L, U)))
```

Any hint/link/suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: An alternative to reconstructing P, L and U from `lu` and `piv` is to call `scipy.linalg.lu` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The permutation vector needs to be interpreted in sequence. If `piv=[1,2,2]` then the following needs to be done in sequence (with zero-based indexing):

1. Row 0 changes with Row 1
2. The new Row 1 changes with Row 2 and
3. The new Row 2 stays the same.

In code this would do the trick:

```
P = np.eye(3)
for i, p in enumerate(piv):
    Q = np.eye(3,3)
    q = Q[i,:].copy()
    Q[i,:] = Q[p,:]
    Q[p,:] = q
    P = np.dot(P, Q)
```

For `piv=[1,2,2]` *P* is

```
[[ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]]
```

This is probably not a very fast way of computing *P* but it does the trick and answers the question.

Comment: Instead of swapping rows of Q and setting P = P.dot(Q), you could interchange the *columns* of P in-place, following the same sequence that you described for the rows.